# How to get the latest row (post) revisions in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table that holds posts and revisions, similar to how wordpress does it.

```
id, parent_id, ...
```

Each root post will have NULL as parent_id. I am looking for a query to get all posts in their latest revisions. That might be the original posts with the `parent_id = NULL` or revisions of posts.

The app I am building is based on laravel, maybe there is an elegant way to solve this in eloquent?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I looked up how wordpress does it, there is an attached taxonomy (revision/published). That way they can filter all published and be sure that these are the posts that they are looking for. Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 1):

The greatest element is either the root element or a child element. To check if a root element is the greatest row you can verify that it has no children (i.e. another row that refers to it as its `parent_id` does `not exist`).

To check if a child element is the greatest element you can verify that another child element with the same `parent_id` and a greater `id` does `not exist`.

```
select * from mytable t1 where (parent_id is null
    and not exists (
        select 1 from mytable t2
        where t2.parent_id = t1.id
    )) or (parent_id is not null
    and not exists (
        select 1 from mytable t2
        where t2.id > t1.id
        and t2.parent_id = t1.parent_id
    ))
```

EDIT

You can group by `coalesce(parent_id,id)` in order to get the children and parents into the same group.

```
select coalesce(parent_id,id), max(id) from mytable
group by coalesce(parent_id,id)
```

Comment: I can see that it gets mighty complicated, i guess adding a current tinyint would simplify things a lot, that way i can only select current = 1 and keep later revisions when checking out an older one. But thanks a lot for your suggestion!

Comment: @rootman I've added simpler version using group by but the current flag is probably your best bet

Answer (score 0):

Save the revisions with a timestamp (if you use Laravel its [schema builder](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema) use `$table->timestamps()` on creation) and order by `created_at` in descending order.

Comment: I already got this, the problem ist that I only need one row per post grouped by parent_id or id for that matter. I can't be sure that there is a revision, so parent_id might be NULL in many cases. that way I cannot use Distinct or Group By. I could first get all IDs and then run a queryloop, but that n+1 problem is something that I want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

I do not 100% your question but if you would like to order them, use the "ORDER BY id DESC" in SQL